# How do I delete all rows after the last row that has content in a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet where I need to delete all the rows below where I am finished with data entry. The problem is I have checkboxes in one column that run the whole length of the sheet so simply deleting all of the blank rows doesn't work.

Here is a screenshot of an example. In this instance, I would want all the rows below row 15 to be deleted, but the checkboxes in Col N prevent the following script from working for me. Thanks a ton for any feedback!

```
function removeEmptyRows(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PB").getRange("A13:H");
  var maxRows = sh.getMaxRows(); 
  var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  sh.deleteRows(lastRow+1, maxRows-lastRow);
}
```

[image]

Comment: From `I would want all the rows below row 15 to be deleted` and your showing image, you want to delete rows from row 15 to the bottom row of all columns. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yeah thats correct

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From `I would want all the rows below row 15 to be deleted` and your showing image, you want to delete rows from row 15 to the bottom row of all columns.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function removeEmptyRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PB");
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange("A13:H" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().findIndex(r => !r.join("")) + 13;
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  sheet.deleteRows(lastRow, maxRows - lastRow + 1);
}
```

- When this script is run, the empty row is searched from `sheet.getRange("A13:H" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues()` and the last row of the range "A13:H" is retrieved. And, using the retrieved last row, all rows after the last row are deleted.

#### Reference:

- [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Answer (score 1):

I think that it would also do the job :

```js
function deleteEmptyRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row.join('') == '') {
      sheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
    }
  }
}
```